# Anyone used Balsamiq mockups for JIRA?

Tags: tools

As both a Balsamiq and JIRA user I'm interested in this [plugin](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/jira).

Has anyone used it?  Any idea if it allows you to save the .bmml files in a specific folder, hence allowing the use of project assets?

Comment: A bit offtopic. Try the webapps stackexchange site.

Comment: This is not a UX question.

Comment: This tool is so useful for UX practice that it perhaps warrants an answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used it yet, so this is somewhat speculative, but as a user of both Jira and Balsamiq, my take on this from the description is:

The plugin allows you to create mockups from within Jira, and probably shows the picture (if referenced correctly) of the mockup in the description of an issue. The latter would be a big advantage (a picture paints a thousand words) as it means you don't have to start balsamiq, nor distribute it to all your Jira users to view the mockup with the issue description.

Also, you probably don't need need to use the plugin to create the mockups. You could simply use the balsamiq desktop app, attach the bmml to an issue, reference it in the text and have Jira show it "inline" in the description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I and my product management/user experience team use Balsamiq Mockups on a regular basis; it's a simple and powerful tool.  You can indeed save bmml files into whatever folder you like on your hard drive—at least, you can if you have the desktop application; I've never used the Web application.

If you want to get an idea for what Balsamiq can do, you can use the full product for a week before you need to buy.

Comment: the question is not for the balsamiq standalone version, but for the plugin version, so your answer is not necessarily true for the Jira plugin version.

Comment: Ah, good point.  My company did have the JIRA plugin for Balsamiq; nobody used it, though.  Rather, we used the desktop application.  That might have been because we were already used to using it; it might also have been that we didn't want our mockups tied so closely to a specific JIRA issue; we generally use them for more than that.